# Sequelize: adding 'include' to a findOne query is not working

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a working NodeJS service running locally against a locally installed MySQL DB.
All queries in the following *app.js* file are working fine, until I try to add the `include` part to the *getUserByEmail* query:

```
include: [
                  {
                    model: models['product'], 
                    as: 'Product' 
                  }
                ]
```

I tried addressing the included model in different ways, such as: `models.Product` - nothing.
As soon as I remove the `include` part again - the query works fine.

The console does no even show me the constructed query (with the include part), however does show the SQL query without the `include` part.

Here are my models (trimmed many columns for simplicity):

**user.js file:**

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../database');

const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: 'ind_email',      
      validate: {
        isEmail: true
      }
    },

    planId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    productId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },

  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'users',
    modelName: 'User',
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: false,
    indexes: [      
      {
        name: 'ind_plan',
        fields: ['planId'],
      },
      {
        name: 'ind_product',
        fields: ['productId'],
      },

    ],
  });

  User.associate = (models) => {
    // define association here
    User.belongsTo(Plan, {
      foreignKey: 'planId',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
    });
    User.belongsTo(Product, {
      foreignKey: 'productId',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
    });

  };

  module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    return User;
  };
```

**product.js file:**

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../database');

const Product = sequelize.define('Product', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    planId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },

  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'products',
    modelName: 'Product',
    indexes: [
      {
        name: 'ind_plan',        
        fields: ['planId'],
      },
     
    ],
  });

  Product.associate = (models) => {
    // define association here
    Product.belongsTo(Plan, {
      foreignKey: 'planId',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
    });
    Product.hasMany(User, {
      onDelete: 'RESTRICT',
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
    });

  };

  module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    return Product;
  };
```

**This is the app.js file sending the queries:**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Op } = require('sequelize');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config(); // Load environment variables from .env file

const { sequelize, models } = require('./models');
sequelize.options.logging = console.log; //Log our Sequelize log to the console - goot for debugging

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

console.log('models in app.js: ', models);

// Sample function to execute a Sequelize query with optional parameters
const executeQuery = async (queryName, args, sql) => {   
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        console.log('Authenticated with query query: ', queryName, args, sql);        

        let result;
        
        switch (queryName) {
          case 'getUserByEmail':
            result = await models['user'].findOne(
              {                
                where: {
                  email: args.email
                },
                include: [
                  {
                    model: models['product'], 
                    as: 'Product'
                  }
                ]
                
              }
            );
            break;

          case 'createUser':              
          result = await models['user'].create(
            {
                name: args.name,
                email: args.email,
                status: args.status,
                billingStatus: args.billingStatus,
                country: args.country,
                phone: args.phone,
                planId: args.planId,
                productId: args.productId,

              }
          );
          break;

          case 'createLog':
            result = await models['log'].create(
              {
                  sourceId: args.sourceId,
                  categoryId: args.categoryId,
                  eventCode: args.eventCode,
                  data: args.data,
        
                }
            );
            break;

          case 'sql':
            const replacedSQL = sql.replace(/\$(\w+)/g, (match, key) => args[key]);
            console.log('About to execute sql: ', replacedSQL);
            result = await sequelize.query(replacedSQL);
            break;
          default:
            throw new Error('Invalid method');
        }
        
        console.log('Query result: ', result);
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Failed to execute the query: ' + error.message);
    } finally {
        // Close the database connection when done
        //sequelize.close(); //Breaks the connection - will return error 500 after the first call.
    }
  };


// Route to handle the POST requests
app.post('/executeQuery', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Received: ', req.body);
      
    try {
      const { queryName, argsIn, sql } = req.body;
    
      const result = await executeQuery(queryName, argsIn, sql);
      res.status(200).json(result);
      
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
  });

// Start the server
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on http://${process.env.DB_HOST}:${port}`);
});
```

In the *models* folder, I also have this **index.js file**:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
dotenv.config(); 

const sequelize  = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USERNAME, process.env.DB_PASSWORD, {
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  dialect: 'mysql',
});

// object to hold all the models to export
const models = {};

// Read all the files from this dir and load the models
fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (
      file.indexOf('.') !== 0 &&
      file !== basename &&
      file.slice(-3) === '.js' &&
      file.indexOf('.test.js') === -1
    );
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const modelPath = path.join(__dirname, file);
    const modelName = file.split('.')[0];
    const modelFactory = require(modelPath);
    const modelInstance = modelFactory(sequelize, DataTypes); // Call the factory function to get the model instance
    models[modelName] = modelInstance;
  });

// Export the sequelize instance and the models
module.exports = { sequelize, models };
```

**From my package.json:**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql2": "^3.5.2",
    "sequelize": "^6.32.1"
  }
```

In the DB I have matching records with data on `productId = 1`.

**What am I missing, please?**

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: No, no errors. Anyway, I fixed it. Will post an answer now...

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's what solved it for me:

**In the model files (e.g. user.js):**

Refer to the `models` in the *model* object I export in index.js, and the model name is all lower case:

```
User.belongsTo(models.product, {
      foreignKey: 'productId',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
    });
    User.hasOne(models.billinginfo, {
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
    });
```

**In the index.js file** located in the models folder: I added this in the end after contructing the models object array:

```
Object.values(models)
    .filter(model => typeof model.associate === 'function')
    .forEach(model => model.associate(models));
```

And finally, **in the query**, I referenced the model with lower-case:

```
result = await models['user'].findOne(
              {                
                where: {
                  email: args.email
                },
                include: [
                  {
                    model: models['product'], // Use the Product model
                    as: 'Product' // Use the alias specified in the association
                  }
                ]
                
              }
            );
```